# How to create list of rows from a table

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table on a webpage.

I want to create a list from rows of the table.

I will then process the list items.

Each table row has an attribute `name="entry"` so I tried to use that:

```
for element in wd.find_elements_by_name("entry"):
     row = element.row
```

This fails because there is no such attribute `row`.

**Question**

How can I populate a Python list with the rows from a HTML table?

Comment: Share your HTML code or URL to the site.

Comment: It is a local website, meaning just for test purposes.
Here is html:
http://freetexthost.com/s2zfoiestx

Comment: Two ways of doing it are, first is: make a Flask API which sends table data to python using ajax and jquery from your frontend or scrape the raw html for the table using scrapy module https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/web-scraping-in-python-using-scrapy/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some searching and trying different options, I finally managed it to work:

```
def get_contact_list(self):
    wd = self.app.wd
    self.open_home_page()
    contacts = []
    for element in wd.find_elements_by_name("entry"):
        cells = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        text = cells[1] and cells[2]
        id = element.find_element_by_name("selected[]").get_attribute("value")
        contacts.append(Contact(name=text, id=id))
    return contacts
```